# Java: Searching in an array of objects, for 2 specific object values

Tags: java, arrays, search, object, binary

I'm doing a project in Java which includes (x,y) coordinates.
I have created a class of Cell which has protected integers X & Y;
Upon initialization, i do a for loop which sets an array of cell by multiplying the X & Y given by the user, say if X= 10 and Y = 10, i create an array of cells[100].

However, how can i search the array fast, without doing a for loop and checking each individual value very time?

Say I'm looking for the object that contains X=5 & y = 3.
I know i can go through with a for loop looking for object with values x and  y, but i was wondering if there is a way to do a binary search and find "a bit faster" the object[i] that contains X=5 and Y=5.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `I have created a class of Cell which has protected integers X & Y; Upon initialization, i do a for loop which sets an array of cell by multiplying the X & Y given by the user` are those different X's and Y's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to arrange the Cell objects in the array in a way so that there is a simple mapping from an X,Y coordinate to the Cell's index in the array.

For example, lets assume that X and Y go from 1 to 10.  Suppose that we then arrange the Cells so that:

```
array[0] = Cell(1, 1);
array[1] = Cell(1, 2);
...
array[9] = Cell(1, 10);
array[10] = Cell(2, 1);
array[11] = Cell(2, 2);
...
array[99] = Cell(10, 10);
```

It should be easy to see that we can calculate the index of Cell(i,j) in the array and fetch the cell as follows:

```
public Cell getCell(Cell[] array, int i, int j) {
    int index = (10 * (i - 1)) + (j - 1);
    return array[index];
}
```

This is the approach that programming languages that support N-dimensional array types typically use to implement them.

This can be trivially modified to deal with cases where:

- the constant 10 is something else
- the matrix is not square,
- the matrix has more than two dimensions
- indexes run from 0 to N - 1 instead of 1 to N
- etcetera

There are various other ways that you could represent 2-D matrices in Java.  The simplest one is just using a `Cell[][] cells` which allows you to access cells as (for example) `cells[i-1][j-1]`.  More complicated representations can be designed that use less space if the matrix is sparse (i.e. cells are missing) at the cost of more complex code and slower access times.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like (if you want to use binary search, anyway) you're setting element 0 to the Cell with `x = 0, y = 0`; element 1 to `x = 0, y = 1`, etc. If so you should be able to trivially compute the exact index of a given Cell:

```
// contains the Cell with x = desiredX, y = desiredY
yourArray[desiredX * X + desiredY];
```

If this is what you're doing, however, it'd probably be simpler to just make a 2-dimensional array:

```
yourArray = new Cell[X][Y];
...
yourArray[desiredX][desiredY];
```

Answer (score 0):

the above two answers show the trivial method for getting the array index fast. id like to propose an alternative- use hashmaps with key, value pairings. the value could be objects. accessing hashmap elements run in constant time..